# Is it possible to use the convolutional functions of TensorFlow with my own neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

That is, a convolutional network consists of its layers of convolution, pooling, etc. And in the end a fully connected network. Well, TF provides all the tools, I want it to be that instead of using the TF network only to use what goes before and the result of that use it in a totally own NETWORK. Is it possible? Could you help me?

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65542469/how-do-i-use-tensorflow-tf-nn-conv2-to-make-a-convolutional-layer

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64448607/tensorflow-2-0-how-can-i-fully-customize-a-tensorflow-training-loop-like-i-can/64449895#64449895