# How to make a custom activation function with trainable parameters in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Would like to understand how to define user defined activation functions for neural networks with two learnable parameters, using tensorflow in python.

Any reference will be helpul or a case study?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a `tf.Variable` within your model, Tensorflow will track its state and will adjust it as any other parameter. Such a `tf.Variable` can be a parameter from your activation function.

Let's start with some toy dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

X = iris[0].astype(np.float32)
y = iris[1].astype(np.float32)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y)).shuffle(25).batch(8)
```

Now, let's create a `tf.keras.Model` and make a parametric ReLU function with the slope being learnable, and also the minimum value (usually 0 for classical ReLU). Let's start with a PReLU slope/min value of 0.1 for now.

```py
slope_values = list()
min_values = list()


class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.prelu_slope = tf.Variable(0.1)
        self.min_value = tf.Variable(0.1)

        self.d0 = Dense(16, activation=self.prelu)
        self.d1 = Dense(32, activation=self.prelu)
        self.d2 = Dense(3, activation='softmax')

    def prelu(self, x):
        return tf.maximum(self.min_value, x * self.prelu_slope)

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        slope_values.append(self.prelu_slope.numpy())
        min_values.append(self.min_value.numpy())
        x = self.d0(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        x = self.d2(x)
        return x


model = MyModel()
```

Now, let's train the model (in eager mode so we can keep the slope values).

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', run_eagerly=True)

history = model.fit(ds, epochs=500, verbose=0)
```

Let's look at the slope. Tensorflow is adjusting it to be the best slope for this task. As you will see it approaches non-parametric ReLU with a slope of 1.

```
plt.plot(slope_values, label='Slope Value')
plt.plot(min_values, label='Minimum Value')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Parametric ReLU Parameters Across Time')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, Can I replace 'prelu' definition as below?. Trying to use `b0+b1x` as my activation function?. `def linear(self, x):
        return self.min_value+ self.prelu_slope*x`

Comment: yes. like i said, as long as yur function is based on tf.Variables Tensorflow will adjust these values as trainable variables

Comment: Was able to track parameter values. Is it possible to track parameter values at the end of each epoch?

Comment: you mean adjusting the weights only at the end of the epoch? i think you'll need a [custom training loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64449895/10908375) for that